# vuejs input not showing value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Input binding issue

:value not showing the value no syntax error but when I use {{ row.item.FEE }}
somewhere else then it works fine.Why it is not showing value in input filed.
Please help.

```
    <b-form-input
      :value="row.item.FEE"
      v-model="model.Fee[row.item.id]"
      @change="changeField('FEE', model.Fee, row.item.id)"
    ></b-form-input>
```

Comment: Why `:value` is needed? `:value` will be ignored.

Comment: @Antonio because I need to show older value :value="row.item.FEE"

Answer (score 1):

I have made some modification to make thing works.

Here is my updated code

```
<b-form-input :value="row.item.MIN" @change="changeField('MIN', $event, row.item.id)"></b-form-input>
```

Removed v-model so I can see the value in input field.
Used $event to get updated value on @Change Event.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

Try passing it to the function instead. Moreover, I do think you should use a method for v-model

```js
methods.modelFee = function(id){
    return this.model.Fee[id]
}
```

```html
    <b-form-input
      v-model="modelFee(row.item.id)"
      @change="changeField('FEE', model.Fee, row.item.id,row.item.FEE)"
    ></b-form-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `:value` and `v-model`, but `:value` will be ignored and not needed.

To initialize the value of `b-form-input`, you can set v-model value `mode.Fee[row.item.id]` as your expected value `row.item.FEE` when the component is mounted.

```
  <b-form-input
      v-model="model.Fee[row.item.id]"
      @change="changeField('FEE', model.Fee, row.item.id)"
    ></b-form-input>
...
  mounted() {
     this.model.Fee[this.row.item.id] = this.row.item.FEE;
  },
```

Comment: Value is not initializing using 
v-model="model.Fee[row.item.id]"

Comment: @Peter Did you try? How do you know about that?

Comment: Yes i have tested with your approach and got error [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined"

Comment: @Peter Could you provide more codes? I can't understand what is your real problem. According to your current codes, I can only say you don't need to use :value.